# Line Breaks when reading an input file by character in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, char, line-breaks

Ok, just to be up front, this IS homework, but it isn't due for another week, and I'm not entirely sure the final details of the assignment.  Long story short, without knowing what concepts he'll introduce in class, I decided to take a crack at the assignment, but I've run into a problem.  Part of what I need to do for the homework is read individual characters from an input file, and then, given the character's position within its containing word, repeat the character across the screen.  The problem I'm having is, the words in the text file are single words, each on a different line in the file.  Since I'm not sure we'll get to use `<string>` for this assignment, I was wondering if there is any way to identify the end of the line without using `<string>`.

Right now, I'm using a simple `ifstream fin;` to pull the chars out.  I just can't figure out how to get it to recognize the end of one word and the beginning of another.  For the sake of including code, the following is all that I've got so far.  I was hoping it would display some sort of `endl` character, but it just prints all the words out run together style.

```
ifstream fin;
char charIn;

fin.open("Animals.dat");
fin >> charIn;
while(!fin.eof()){
    cout << charIn;
    fin >> charIn;
}
```

A few things I forgot to include originally:

I must process each character as it is input (my loop to print it out needs to run before I read in the next char and increase my counter).  Also, the length of the words in 'Animals.dat' vary which keeps me from being able to just set a number of iterations.  We also haven't covered fin.get() or .getline() so those are off limits as well.

Honestly, I can't imagine this is impossible, but given the restraints, if it is, I'm not too upset.  I mostly thought it was a fun problem to sit on for a while.

Comment: Well, hopefully your teacher will be more pleased if you replace `while (!fin.eof())` with `while (/*read something*/)`.

Comment: If the file is open as a text file, not a binary file, then on both Unix and Windows, the line ending will appear as newline, `'\n'`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the position repetition description? Do you mean the word "cat" would become "caattt" ?

Comment: Craig, that's exactly correct.  "boy" would output "booyyy" and "comment" would output "coommmmmmmeeeeennnnnnttttttt".  This requirement makes it so that i have to keep up with the char's position within its word, which is why I have to distinguish the line breaks.

Comment: I want to point out that this is an example of a homework question that is posed very well compared to most. This isn't "give me teh codez", it isn't an assignment posted word for word, and it isn't a vague description of an assignment that no one will understand. It has a descriptive title, a specific problem, and a clear solution. It also includes an attempt at the problem. It goes to show that homework questions are just as reasonable as any others as long as they are posted properly.

Comment: I wish someone would say "give me teh codez" in an SO question.

Comment: I just want to thank everyone who answered and contributed.  My main reason for asking was to see if there was a solution given what we'd covered in class already.  Today, he introduced .get, so, for anyone who cared enough to wonder, that's the route he wanted us to go.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>>` operator ignores whitespace, so you'll never get the newline character. You can use c-strings (arrays of characters) even if the `<string>` class is not allowed:

```
ifstream fin;
char animal[64];

fin.open("Animals.dat");

while(fin >> animal) {
  cout << animal << endl;
}
```

When reading characters from a c-string (which is what `animal` is above), the last character is always 0, sometimes represented '\0' or `NULL`. This is what you check for when iterating over characters in a word. For example:

```
c = animal[0];
for(int i = 1; c != 0 && i < 64; i++)
{
    // do something with c
    c = animal[i];
}
```

Comment: Note: you can turn off whitespace skipping with a single sticky manipulator , [noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), thereby making the need to read into any temp buffer moot.

Comment: And the way to read characters directly is with the `read` or `get` functions, not `>>` which is for *formatted* I/O.

Comment: Wait, -1. The `operator >>` isn't aware of the array size here, it's treating it as a `char *` and using the same string semantics as with `std::string`… but no memory safety. Don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array of chars? You can try it as follow:

```
    #define MAX_WORD_NUM 20
    #define MAX_STR_LEN 40 //I think 40 is big enough to hold one word.
    char words[MAX_WROD_NUM][MAX_STR_LEN];
```

Then you can input a word to the words.

```
    cin >> words[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This solution doesn't address my initial problem, where reading single characters, I can't figure out how to distinguish the end of one word.  They vary in length, so there's no way to say read in this many then move to the next word.  Also, this reminds me of something I need to clarify in my question.

Comment: @jvance: Once the word is stored in an array, accessing individual characters is easy.

Comment: Yeah, then he can do what he wants easily.

Comment: After reading your reply again (and in the light of some of the others) I see where I was mistaken the first time through.  Thanks again for answering, though.